# What would happen if water splashed on a 12v power supply when under load?

Tags: power-supply, water

If I am running a 40A 12v power supply at approximately 32A, and a large quantity of water splashes onto it, what physical effects will occur in a worst case scenario.  I'm sure I can expect short circuits within the PSU and for my fuse to blow.  Will any sparking occur?  If so, could they make it out of the PSU case?  And could they persist for long periods or would the power stop flowing upon the first spark?

For the purposes of this question assume hard water with electrically conductive contaminants.  Assume further that the PSU is hooked up to a power switch with a 45A fuse hooked up to a 110v / 15A outlet.

For clarification: This did not actually occur.  I've just been playing around with a PSU doing some experiments and the question occurred to me when my daughter walked into the room with a cup of water.

Comment: Worst case, you get electrocuted, the thing blows up starts a fire, burns your house down, your wife leaves you, and your daughter runs away with that 40 year old tattooed guy from the carnival.

Comment: The best case - nothing happens. You go to find a wipe to clean it up, get distracted by a commercial about the weekly lottery draw of $50M, go to the closest store, buy a ticket and win.. Worth a try?

Comment: @Trevor -- oh my, not THAT tattooed guy, better protect the PSU then.

Comment: As a parent you should prevent your children from accidentally causing any form of danger.  Maybe keep the PSU and load out of reach from children?

Comment: A 110V/15A outlet is protected by a 15A breaker (or maybe 20A, that value isn't accurate), and if it really DOES only have a 45A fuse, that's a fire-safety violation.

Comment: @Trevor is always the optimist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a reasonably good possibility the supply will be damaged, so you should just assume it will be.  Whatever is connected to the output might also get damaged due to over-voltage.  You can not count on a excessive input current condition such that a fuse would blow.

However, the worst issue is loss of isolation between the AC input and the DC output.  You have to basically assume that any part of the DC side is essentially connected to the hot side of the AC line.  That can kill or injure any person that happens to touch the supposedly safe DC and ground at the same time.

If you really think this scenario is a possibility, make sure to use a ground fault interrupting breaker on the AC not near where the water can splash.

Comment: Downvoters, please explain what you think is wrong.

Comment: wow... +1 for GFI... That's actually something anyone working on electronics projects should have installed at their work bench. And also why food and drinks is a NO NO at the workstation.

Comment: Out of interest, is there any safety advantage having it at the workbench, rather than at the breaker box? I imagine it's more convenient, but is it safer?

Comment: @BeB: Wherever the GFI breaker is, it shouldn't be where the same splashing hazard can get to it too.  Otherwise, the water could make a conductive path around the breaker.

Comment: @BeB00 at the breaker box can be problematic if it is not within line of sight of the workstation since flipping it back on remotely can start a fire back at the workstation. Outlet style GCIs close to and higher than the workbench are ideal. As OLIN mentions though... they need to be somewhere they wont also get wet.